# can't find error on my script

Tags: authentication, vbscript, html

I have a small VBScript that opens a webpage and enters my login credentials. However, I always get an error and don't know how to fix it.

```
Call Main

Function Main
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://x10hosting.com/sso/login"
    Wait IE
    With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("identifier").value = "FAKEEMAIL@my.com"
        .getElementByID("password").value = "FAKEPASS"
        .getElementsByName("button button-rounded button-primary")(0).Submit
    End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

The error is:

```
line: 11
char: 9
Error: Object required: 'getElementsByName(...)(...)'
code: 800A01A8
sources: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers please see the post. I edited then

Answer (score 0):

```
With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("identifier").value = "FAKEEMAIL@my.com"
    .getElementByID("password").value = "FAKEPASS"
    .getElementsByName("button button-rounded button-primary")(0).Submit
End With
```

Could it because you are using the getElementsByName wrong?
getElementsByName looks for attributes with that name, but it seems you used class names.

[Check this for getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

You need to use getElementsByClassName.

[Check this for getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)